# Content Filter is enabled and the last definition update was over 12 hours ago

Tags: spam, exchange-2010, microsoft-forefront-2010

Microsoft Forefront Protection for exchange server 2010 has been installed and I get updates for all of the engines except the spam one.

These are the health points I have installed:

- Spam definition update
- Selected engines updated
- All engine updates enabled
  vSelected engines update period

All of these except the spam definition show up with the green check. The spam has a message that reads

> Content Filter is enabled and the last
>   definition update was over 12 hours
>   ago.

I found this link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358875.aspx.

If antispam is enabled, the server requires Internet connectivity in order to obtain and download the definition updates for the Cloudmark antispam engine directly from the Cloudmark Web sites. Also, ensure that proxy information has been entered, if required. The following URLs (and any subdomains under them) and the use of http and https must be allowed through the firewall:

- cdn-microupdates.cloudmark.com
- lvc.cloudmark.com
- tracks.cloudmark.com
- pki.cloudmark.com

So I added *.cloudmark.com to my trusted sites list in IE on the server, but this didn't seem to help, the other engines all passed without this entry in the list.

This is a fresh install, so I don't think this is a new issue, just a not configured thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My exchange server had some AD issues. When those were resolved I was able to get the new updates.